# Is it okay have database logic in my Auth class?

Tags: php, oop

I have loads of domain objects which use data mappers to do the needed database work so the domain objects have no idea about the mappers or where the data is coming to keep a high level of abstraction. Now my question is I have an `Auth` object which I use like this early in my applications startup:

```
$auth = $container->get('auth');
$auth->isAllowed($pageName, $accountType);
```

At the moment I do my do my SQL work inside the class and it works but something tells me I am doing it wrong. Is there a better way to achieve this?

I suppose there is a way of doing it where I put my `$auth` object into an `$authDAO` or `$authMapper` object to lookup the access control list in the database but that just does not make sense to me since an `Auth` object is not really what you would call a "Domain Object" in my eyes definitely does not need a data mapper.

Is it okay to have database logic in my `Auth` object? or is there a better way to handle database logic/work for non domain objects?

Comment: You're using too many words i am not sure are clear in the context you provided. The base question is: why does it look weird to you? think about the reason. The other question is: is my object doing more than it should?

Comment: It looks weird to me because everything should be at a high level of abstraction and mixing application logic and database logic looks bad to me because I am used to having no database logic in my domain objects by using data mappers and repositories.

Comment: Why wouldn't a user be a 'domain object'?  More important than fitting into some narrowly defined arbitrary categories in you head is keeping things consistent - if everything else that's persisted is handled one way, what arguments can you make for making users a special case?

Comment: @SeanMcSomething is completely right, and that was the purpose for my questions as well.

Comment: As long as you only authenticate against the database, having the logic inside the general Auth class is okay. It's pragmatic and good enough for your current setup. It's when you start to allow authentication against several authentication providers that you will want to abstract things, e.g. use a general Authentication Facade that delegates authentication to specialized Authentication Providers.